# Does not add user in centOS 5.5

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, centos5

When I run a shell script. It shows some errors. I run script on **centOS 5.5**.

This is the part of my shell script where its show error.

**PART OF CODE**

```
if ! id service >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    doit 'CREATING "service" user' 'whereis adduser -c SERVICE -d /home/service -u 2000 -g 2000 -s /bin/bash service ; echo service | passwd --stdin service'
fi
```

**doit code**

```
doit ()
{
    local msg=$1
    shift
    if [ "$msg" ]
    then
        echo "$msg"
    fi
    if [ -z "$DONOTHING" ]
    then
        eval $*
    fi
}
```

**ERROR**

```
CREATING "service" user
adduser: /usr/sbin/adduser /usr/share/man/man8/adduser.8.gz
whereis [ -sbmu ] [ -SBM dir ... -f ] name...
passwd: Unknown user name 'service'.
```

Comment: What are you doing in `doit`?

Comment: trying to create user.

Comment: What *exactly* are you doing? Show us the code.

Comment: For some reasons I can not show the codes. yes, I can show the part that you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to drop `whereis` from your command.

Comment: I also do that....it shows
`CREATING "service" user

*FILE LOCATION*  adduser: command not found

passwd: Unknown user name 'service'.`

Comment: @FreakyCheeky Is `/usr/sbin/` in `$PATH` ?

Comment: @FreakyCheeky It needs to be there.

Comment: Tell me how can I resolve this error. Because this is the very first step of my script.

Comment: He just did. Remove call to whois, and add /usr/sbin to PATH.

Comment: I added `/user/sbin` in PATH, but it still shows the same above error.

Comment: @FreakyCheeky It's `/usr/sbin`, not `/user/sbin`.

Comment: yes, I run this command `PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin` then I start runnig the script, shows same error.

Comment: @FreakyCheeky You need to export it. I'll stop answering here, I'm already tired of this question.

Comment: @cnicutar I did that, but it shows same error. Please solve this.

Comment: @cnicutar I edited the question, add the doit function. Now please help me.

Comment: @FreakyCheeky Persistent. Have you tried running it as `root` ?

Comment: @FreakyCheeky If you run the command manually (the `adduser` part), does it work ?

Comment: when I write this on terminal `adduser`, it shows command not found.

Can I do chat for just one minute so that I can easily sole this problem.

Comment: @FreakyCheeky Do a `ls -l /usr/sbin/adduser`.

Comment: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Feb 10  2013 /usr/sbin/adduser -> useradd`

It gives above output

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24266/discussion-between-freakycheeky-and-cnicutar)

Comment: @FreakyCheeky Well then I guess that was it. `/usr/sbin/` wasn't in `$PATH`.